# Is there a way to un-poison a weapon poisoned with an ooze barrel?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

There is a crafting recipe in-game that lets you combine a weapon with an ooze barrel to add poison damage to a weapon. While fine and dandy, I need to un-poison it so i can fight some undead effectively.

Is there a crafting recipe that'll un-poison a weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on comments on PSAs about abusing ooze barrels for unlimited poison enchantments like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/DivinityOriginalSin/comments/71nrqf/protip_always_carry_a_ooze_barrel/), it looks like you are unable to remove the poison enchantment once you've applied it, so think carefully before poisoning all your stuff or make sure to keep a spare set for when you're *not* fighting undead enemies.

> Honestly, I wouldn't recommend applying poison damage to your characters off the bat like that. The extra poison damage heals undead enemies, which are extremely prevalent. If you don't plan to fight any in the foreseeable future, it's nice though.

---

> Only downside to poisoning all your weapons is that you fight a lot of undead, at least in the parts of the game that I've played through so far and any damage done with poison heals them.
>
> Yep, this is a legit problem that has made me completely forego any weapons/enchantspoison-based spells/runes that do poison damage. Same with Fire damage to certain enemies, but those are far less prominent.

---

> Keep in mind that if you add poison to your weapons and dont have a spare set you are effectively lowering your weapon DPS against undead. Not to mention the poison chance which is probably pretty game losing.

---

I'd read a suggestion or two that claimed since combining a poisoned weapon with cloth would remove poison in real life, it would work, but unfortunately, it does not.

> I've heard combining the poisoned weapon with cloth can remove the poison effect. Haven't started a new game yet to test crafting, though.
>
> Cloth scraps? Doesn't work.